# How to access to the value of attribute "permission" of yt:accessControl of YouTube

Tags: c#, youtube-api

How to access to the value of attribute "permission" of   yt:accessControl

**Reason for this :**  I need to exclude videos which are not embdable or private.

i.e

```
    <yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='commentVote' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='rate' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='embed' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='list' permission='allowed'/>
    <yt:accessControl action='syndicate' permission='allowed'/>
```

**What I have in my code :**

```
        //Feed<Video> feed
       foreach (Video entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            positionNoOnImport++;
            anyrecordFound = true;
            String catg = "";
            int i = 0;
            foreach (AtomCategory cat in entry.Categories)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    catg += cat.Term + ",";
                i++;
            }

            string sec = "0";
            if (entry.Media.Duration != null)
            {
                sec = entry.Media.Duration.Seconds;
            }
        // here what I tried for accessControl

         //entry.AccessControl :: but this option is not available or not accessible 
         //entry. ??? might be something missing ..


        // so how to get value of accessControl tag, 
        // and I also unable to fetch/Get  <noembed/> tag..
```